# Increment value in an array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to calculate the number of times a specific number is rolled in a set of six six-sided dice, to determine wether or not I have three of a kind, four of a kind, etc.

I can pull the face value of each die rolled and compare it to the faces on a 6 sided die but can't get the "qtyRolled" key/value to increment.

```
    func rollDice() {
    currentRoll.removeAll()

    for _ in currentDiceArray {
        let num: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(currentDieFaceArray.count))
        let currentDieData = currentDieFaceArray[Int(num)]
        let faceValue = currentDieData["faceValue"]
        currentRoll.append(faceValue as! Int)
    }
    print(currentRoll)
    getQtyOfDieFaces()
    //checkForScoringCombos()
}

func getQtyOfDieFaces() {
    for die in currentRoll {
        for dieData in currentDieFaceArray {
            var currentDieData = dieData
            let qtyRolled = currentDieData["qtyRolled"] as! Int
            let faceValue = currentDieData["faceValue"] as! Int
            print("faceValue: \(faceValue)")
            print("Die: \(die)")
            if faceValue == die {
                currentDieData["qtyRolled"] = qtyRolled + 1 as AnyObject
            }
        }
    }
    for currentDieData in currentDieFaceArray {
        print(currentDieData["qtyRolled"]!)
    }
}
```

Here are my data structures

```
var currentDieFaceArray = [[String:AnyObject]]()
var currentDiceArray:[[String:AnyObject]] = [[:]]
var currentRoll: [Int] = []
```

Comment: It's possible to work it all out, but you should explain your data structures (in particular, currentDieFaceArray as an array of dictionaries?). These could probably be simplified to structs/classes with Int members, and you'd find it easier to see what was going on. It'd also be more efficient to update the quantity within the rollDice func, where you already have the rolled value and access to the correct currentDieData.

Comment: I had tossed around the idea of the structs/classes, could you possibly give some direction as to how this could be done.  Classes vs. Structs?  I'm a programmer from way back, like the 90's but haven't done any programming in about 25 years, as you can imagine, things have changed a little, lol.  I had the first color laptop at the college I attended if that tells you anything.

Comment: A nice intro is in the main Swift book: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend ditching the dictionaries unless you really need them, as you're really just dealing with properties of a struct/class. I'm going to assume you're using the currentDieFaceArray method so that you can make this generic for non-linear dice faces of other dimensions (e.g. you can have a four-sided dice with the face values [1, 4, 6, 8]). If this isn't the case, you can simplify further I'm sure with a simple array of counts. But here's an example with your method (probably has other possible optimisations).

```
class DieFaceDefn
{
  let faceValue : Int
  var countThisRoll : Int = 0

  init(faceValue: Int)
  {
    self.faceValue = faceValue
  }
}


var diceFaces: [DieFaceDefn] = []
let numberOfCurrentDice = 5

func setupDice()
{
    diceFaces.append(DieFaceDefn(faceValue: 1))
    diceFaces.append(DieFaceDefn(faceValue: 2))
    ...
}

var currentRoll: [Int] = []
func rollDice()
{
  currentRoll.removeAll()
  diceFaces.forEach { $0.countThisRoll = 0 }

  for _ in 0..<numberOfCurrentDice
  {
    let num: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(diceFaces.count))
    let currentDieData = diceFaces[Int(num)]
    let faceValue = currentDieData.faceValue
    currentRoll.append(faceValue)
    currentDieData.countThisRoll += 1
  }
  print(currentRoll)
  diceFaces.forEach { print("\($0.faceValue): \($0.countThisRoll)") }
}
```

Comment: appreciate the help and advice.  Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: No problem. FYI, I don't think laptops existed when I went to college.